# Determining whether the stack grows downwards by computing the difference in addresses of local variables

Tags: c, memory

Would computing the difference in the addresses of the stack variables not be the way to determine whether the stack grows upwards or downwards?

```
int a;
int b;
printf ("Difference: %d\n", (&b - &a); // if > 0, stack grows downwards
```

Comment: "Downward" doesn't necessarily make sense because that depends entirely on perspective. I don't think though that variable order is guaranteed, so no, I don't think this will work. It *seems* like it follows declaration order when the datatypes are the same size, but I don't think it has to be the case necessarily

Comment: the examples I've seen either do using recursive functions or passing a local variable to a function and comparing the differences

Comment: @Carcigenicate mind elaborating on the variable ordering part? `int a` executes first and `int b` after so shouldn't they be placed accordingly?

Comment: Just because a variable is declared before another, it isn't necessarily put in the same order in memory. If the compiler thinks it can align the stack better with a different configuration, it may store them in whatever order it wants. In my experience, when the data is the same size, it seems to maintain the order since either would result in the same alignment, but I don't think that's required.

Comment: @Carcigenicate so `b` could be put above `a` or vice versa in stack memory and is indeterminate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implementation-specific aspects aside, comparing addresses of local variables in the same function is not a good way to determine if the stack grows up or down.  This is because the implementation is free order variables in memory any way it sees fit.

Variables within a particular function's stack frame will typically be together however, so you might be able to do this by comparing the address of a variable in one function with the address of a variable in a called function.  For example:

```
void check_stack(void *ptr)
{
    int var;
    if (ptr) {
        if ((uintptr_t)&var > (uintptr_t)ptr) {
            printf("stack is growing up\n");
        } else {
            printf("stack is growing down\n");
        }
    } else {
        check_stack(&var);
    }
}
```

And call the function as `check_stack(NULL);`

Also, note that the pointers are first casted to `uintptr_t`.  That is because using relational operators on unrelated pointers invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  A `uintptr_t` is an integer type guaranteed to be able to hold a converted pointer value, and it is those values that are compared.

Comment: aren't `var` & `ptr` the same thing after the first recursive call?

Comment: In the recursive call, `ptr` would be the address of `var` from the *previous* call. Each call to the function has its own `var`.

Comment: so this way we are ensuring the ordering remains intact since we are comparing the variables located in different stacks as opposed to comparing the local variables in the same function?

Comment: @xyf We're comparing variables in different stack *frames*.  It's the same stack, just a different part of it.

Comment: @xyf The same stack, different stack frames. Since stacks by design can only be added to the top, you know that when you call a function, its stack frame will be placed above that of the calling function.

Comment: yeah my bad that's what I meant...but why are variables not placed in the same order on the stack? optimization reasons?

Comment: @xyf Yes, compilers will typically reorder variables for optimization purposes.

Comment: and it's not related to storing something in the array for instance, which will always go from low to high memory?

Comment: @xyf Elements of an array are always ordered from lowest to highest.

Comment: right so you can't really use that to determine the stack growth...

Comment: @xyf Did this post answer your question?  If so, feel free to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).